# I'm getting an error "Tabs cannot be edited right now (user may be dragging a tab)" on tab update/activate/focus event in chrome 91

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After the recent Chrome update my extension started to fire "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Tabs cannot be edited right now (user may be dragging a tab)" when I attempt to use chrome.tabs API.
There is not much info on this issue yet, but I believe this is a browser bug. In the meantime my extension causes the chrome tabs to switch noticeably slower, that it used to be. It now takes a couple of seconds to change the tab. So I'm looking for a workaround.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This is [a bug](https://crbug.com/1213925).

Answer (score 10):

The only solution that I have found so far is to put my handlers in a timeout like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
           // The old listener handler moves here
        }, 100);
    });
```

But there must be a better way, right?

Comment: Hi @Sergey do you have found a better solution. I have been able to fix the issue with this solution. But, I think it's not good practice.

Answer (score 3):

You will still get errors but at least it will work

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {getActivatedTab();});
function getActivatedTab(){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        try{
            if(tabs[0]!=undefined){
            
                console.log(tabs[0].url);   
            }
        }
        catch(err){
            setTimeout(function() {
            getActivatedTab();
            },100);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: that works fine thanks ... submitted my extension with that fix :D

Answer (score 2):

create separate function outside of chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener.
this way work for me.

```
function insertScript(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.get(tab.tabId, function (info) {
    console.log(info);
   });
}
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (tab) {
   setTimeout(function () {
     insertScript(tab);
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1213925) in Chrome91, as pointed by @wOxxOm.

This patch is suggested if you are making a lot of calls to e.g. `xchrome.tabs.query`

```
const ChromeWrapper = {
  chromeTabsQuery: function (params, callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query(params, tabs => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          //console.warn("Patch for xchrome.tabs.query (Chrome 91).");
          ChromeWrapper.chromeTabsQuery(params, callback)
        }, 100); // arbitrary delay
      } else {
        callback(tabs)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

And then, just replace the instances of

```
xchrome.tabs.query(...
```

with:

```
ChromeWrapper.chromeTabsQuery(...
```

Answer (score 0):

...Alright,
I don't have an really better solution other than setTimeout, as I don't really see where are the message/event posted after the tab done, so what I do is also add a `setTimeout` to do some "trial and error".

But how I do it is to override the original `chrome.tabs.get` so that we can have the same experience as we use it as expected way. (And easily to delete this snippet when they finally fix it some day)

Here is my code, cheers

```js
    chrome.tabs.get = function () {
        const orig_get = chrome.tabs.get.bind(chrome.tabs);
        return async function (tabId) {
            return new Promise(
                resolve => {
                    var tryGet = () => {
                        orig_get(tabId)
                        .then(resolve)
                        .catch(() => {
                            // console.log("retry get");
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                tryGet(tabId);
                            }, 50);
                        })
                    };
                    tryGet();
                }
            )
        }
    }();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I started getting this bug under a unique set of conditions, where if you would recently drag and move the tab to a new position, then switch to another tab then back to this one, it would fire this error even though the drag event was over and done with. It appears to be some kind of bug, but in my case it was happening if I tried to delete a tab shortly after a drag event ended on that tab.

The solution I found was just to recursively retry the main function that conditionally checks if we need to "delete tab". Basically, I had event listeners for onActivated, onFocused, onUpdated, however my final backup option? My last line of defense, so to speak? Is a recursive function call in the background script that checks, every 1 second, what URL we're on, and if it meets the conditions required to trigger a deletion event. Obviously not the ideal solution, but it's 100% workable to handle the cases where the event listeners break down due to some weird Chrome errors.

```
setInterval(() => {
  // console.log("Checking what URL we're on + if the tab needs to be closed...");
  CheckForURLMatch_ThenMaybeCloseTab();
}, 1000);
```