# How to get current tab URL using Manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do I get the URL of the current tab in the background service worker in MV3?

Here's what I have:

```
let currentURL;

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(handleBrowserActionClicked);

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  console.log("Command:", command);
  handleBrowserActionClicked();
});

function handleBrowserActionClicked() {
  togglePlugin();
}
function togglePlugin() {
  console.log("toggle plugin");
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "activateFeedback" });
  });
}

// Fires when the active tab in a window changes.
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function () {
    console.log("TAB CHANGED")
    //firstTimeRunning = true
    //feedbackActivated = false
    currentURL = getTab()
    .then(console.log("Current URL: " + currentURL))
})

// Fired when a tab is updated.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function () {
    console.log("TAB UPDATED")
    currentURL = getTab() // line 32
    .then(console.log("Current URL: " + currentURL))
})

async function getTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(chrome.tabs[0].url); // line 38
  return tab;
}
```

Right now the service worker is logging "Current URL: [object Promise]" instead of, for example, "https://www.google.com"

It is also giving an error in the console (see comments above for line numbers)

```
background.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at getTab (background.js:38)
    at background.js:32
```

I think it may be something to do with my limited knowledge of promises!

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You function `getTab` seems not right, you are currently trying to query on the url. Not on the query options. The following function should work.

```
async function getTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tabs[0].url;
}
```

Also make sure you have the `tabs` permission.

In the listener you also don't use the correct async/promise method two examples using `Promise.then` and `await`.

`Promise.then`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function () {
    console.log("TAB UPDATED")
    getTab().then(url => {
        console.log(url);
    })
})
```

`await`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async function () {
    console.log("TAB UPDATED")
    let url = await getTab()
    console.log(url)
})
```

For the "Error: Tabs cannot be queried right now (user may be dragging a tab)." error you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67986078/6098780), which suggest a small delay before querying the tab url.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. When I run then I get a different error message "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Tabs cannot be queried right now (user may be dragging a tab)."

I am not dragging the tab - I am simply activating the extension when the tab is fully loaded.

It is also still logging "Current URL: [object Promise]"

I have the tabs permission.

Comment: I updated the answer with two examples how to solve the [object Promise] and the dragging a tab.

Comment: Working now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const tab = (await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }))[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use "**activeTab**" permission in *manifest.json*

Add **activeTab** in your manifest.json.

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
],
```

And In **Background.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
 console.log(tab.url);
});
```

I'm sure It will help you to get the current tab URL.
useful links - [ActiveTab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/)