# Chrome Extension: In background.js , I am not able to get the Tab details. I tried 3 methods but the result in undefined

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In background js:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo)=>{
        var tabId=activeInfo.tabId;
        console.log("tab switched: "+tabId);
        chrome.tabs.get(tabId,(tab)=>{
          console.log("getTabById: "+tab);
        });
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
         
          console.log("getTabByUsingSelected: "+tab);
        });
        chrome.tabs.query({"active":true,"currentWindow":true,'lastFocusedWindow': true}, (tabs)=>{
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          }else{
          if(tabs!==undefined){
           console.log("getTabByQuery: "+tabs[0].url);
          }
        }
        }); 
      });
```

Manifest:

```
"manifest_version":2
         "permissions":[
        "storage",  
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "background":{
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
```

The response is always undefined when I am not using a query. Query is working only first time

Comment: This is a recent bug, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67806780).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working for me now.