# Recently I was getting this error in my extension 'Unchecked runtime.lastError: Tabs cannot be queried right now (user may be dragging a tab).'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I fixed it by using the below code but, I know this is not the right way to fix it. Can anyone please give me an alternative solution for this :)

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       // code
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Have you just read this thread?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806779/im-getting-an-error-tabs-cannot-be-edited-right-now-user-may-be-dragging-a-ta

Comment: Yes Robbi I saw that, but the results are same, we should not use setTimeout() function to resolve this issue. I need any other possible solution for this fix :)